# c++ get registry key returns only one char

Tags: c++, registry

I'm trying to retrieve a value of a key but i'm only getting the first char of the value..
can anyone help?

my code:

```
void dealWithRegistry()
{
    HKEY regkey1;
    char data[100];
    DWORD datasize = sizeof (data) / sizeof (char);
    LONG rc = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &regkey1);
    if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "there was a problem openning" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        rc = RegGetValue (regkey1, NULL, L"AppData", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, (void*) data, &datasize);
        if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << data << endl;
            cout << "there was a problem getting the value" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << data << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably returning Unicode data and you are only printing the first character.  A quick test of that would be to change the call to `RegGetValueA`.

Comment: @Tom.  I'm glad you got it working. The other possible solution is to use TCHAR instead of char and then it will have the appropriate type (WCHAR or char) based on the build attributes (Unicode or ANSI).